# Firefox WebExtensions: can not get canceled request data

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla, firefox-addon-webextensions

During playing with Firefox WebExtensions I've created a simple add-on that cancels certain POST request and reads its params:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "description": "Canceled webRequests data",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "webRequest-demo",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "http://kamil.hism.ru/pocs/*"
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

**background.js**

```
var pattern = "http://kamil.hism.ru/pocs/simple_form_action";

function cancel(requestDetails) {
  console.log("Canceling: " + requestDetails.url);
  console.log(requestDetails.requestBody.formData.some_field)
  // debugger
  return { cancel: true };
}

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  cancel,
  { urls:[pattern] },
  ["requestBody", "blocking"]
);
```

The target page with form is located here: `http://kamil.hism.ru/pocs/simple_form.html`

`requestDetails` contains `requestBody` that should contain `formData` object with all passed data. In Chrome it works good, but in Firefox `requestBody` contains only `raw` array with an ArrayBuffer object. I've tried to convert it to string using `String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(requestDetails.requestBody.raw[0]));`, but it returns empty string.

So, the question is: does anybody know how to solve that problem and get all data from canceled request using Firefox WebExtension add-on? Maybe it's some bug in Mozilla's implementation of WebExtensions?

Comment: which `firefox` browser version do you use?

Comment: @pritishvaidya the latest firefox dev edition version 52.0a2 (2017-01-09) (64-bit)

Comment: I think you might need to *modify* the `content header` and set it to `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` by using the following [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/HttpHeaders)

Comment: @pritishvaidya, I'm not sure it'll help since this is a bug in Mozilla's implementation of WebExtensions itself, see the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [help](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/dev-addons/2017-January/002463.html) of Mozilla community it turned out this is actually a bug in Firefox WebExtensions. Although I couldn't find the exact release note or bug in bugzilla related to it, **Firefox Nightly build (53.0a) doesn't have this issue**:

[image]

Hopefully soon those changes from Nightly would be merged into Release channel.

Comment: oh ,forgot to check it .